# Meteor.js : How to access schema metadata(field type) from afQuickField in a helper function

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Please tell me how to access the scheam defintions from a afQuickField helper method. I want to render differently based on type.

Lets say I have a simple schema defined

```
mySchema = new SimpleSchema({
 numberField: {
  type: Number,
  defaultValue: 3
},
 stringField: {
  type: String,
},...
```

I want a helper method that tells me the type of field I am using.

```
Template.myQuickField.helper({
  fieldMetaDataString: function() {
    let type = ??What to put here. Code that looks at Simple Schema  definition for the field and tells me its type??
    if(type===String){
     return true;
    }
  return false;
```

}
});

Now I want to wrap the afQuickField into a template of my own so that I can render it differently depending on what type the field is. Note this is a simplified example. I want to do more then change the style.

```
<template name="myQuickField">
  {{#if fieldMetaDataString}}
   {{> afQuickField id=id name=name style="stringstuff"}}
   {{else}}
   {{> afQuickField id=id name=name style="otherstuff"}}
   {{/if}}
```

EDIT:
I guess I should of said I am then using the myQuickField in the autoform.
and I will use it in other collections as well. So I also need to know how do I find out the value of collection from the auto form inside the field helperMethod.

```
<template name="myForm">
 {{#autoForm collection="mySchema"  type="insert"}}
 <fieldset>
   {{> **myQuickField** name='numberField'}}
   {{> **myQuickField** name='stringField'}}

 </fieldset>   
 {{/autoForm}}
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Myschemadef ={
 numberField: {
  type: Number,
  defaultValue: 3
},
 stringField: {
  type: String,
}
}

mySchema = new SimpleSchema(Myschemadef);

Template.myQuickField.helper({
  fieldMetaDataString: function(feld) {
    let type = Myschemadef[feld].type;
    return type===String;
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always export the schema before you attach it and then import it in the template js file.

```
export const schema = new SimpleSchema({
  stringField: {
    type: String
  },
  numberField: {
    type: Number
  }
});
```

and then import it

```
import { schema } from '../imports/api/data/data.js'
Template.myQuickField.helper({
  setStyle: function(name) {
    let type = schema._schema[name].type
    if(type===String){
     return "stringStyle";
    } else if (type===Number){
     return "numberStyle"
    }
});
```

inside myQuickField Template

```
{{> afQuickField id=id name={{name}} style="{{setStyle name}}"}}
```

the autoform template is the same

```
<template name="myForm">
 {{#autoForm collection="mySchema"  type="insert"}}
 <fieldset>
   {{> myQuickField name='numberField'}}
   {{> myQuickField name='stringField'}}

 </fieldset>   
 {{/autoForm}}
 </template>
```

Comment: please see my last edit. I dont think I explained my need correctly the first time.  I need a helper method that finds the collection and the field. Is there a way to access the autoforms collection variable from myQuickField.helpers

Comment: ya, it's the same, but instead of static strings, pass the name parameter